# Will a SQL view filtered by large datetime always provide current data?

Tags: sql, date, ddl, sql-view, sqldatetime

If I create a view today for a table that continuously keeps getting data, using date filtering from 1900 and 2100, for example, will that "copy" become truncated to the moment that I build the view or since it is being filtered to a very large date will it keep showing the current data to the users that can access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create a view today for a table that continuasly keeps getting data, [...] will it keep showing the current data to the users that can Access it?

Yes. A view does not actually stores data, it is just a sql query. Whenever you access the view, that sql query is executed under the hood. So basically a view always reflect the data that is stored in its underlying, physical tables.

**[Here is the small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=738b40fa8268f93ffa49f34bf640e028)** that demonstrates this behavior:

```
create table mytable (id int, val varchar(5));
insert into mytable(id, val) values(1, 'foo')

create view myview as select id, val from mytable;
select * from myview;
```

```
id | val
-: | :--
 1 | foo
```

```
insert into mytable values(2, 'bar');
select * from myview;
```

```
id | val
-: | :--
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
```

Comment: A Pointer basically then? No space ocupied even if I create hundreds of views based on huge tables? I knew it would create a virtual copy based on the select and it would be allways accessible but allways had this dates/space doubt....

Comment: @Eunito: yes, you are correct. The database dictionnary just stores the definition of the view, there is no physical storage.